# Is it correct to say <Artist name> on vocals?

Tags: grammar

I'm designing an album cover, and I'm listing the contributing artists and their instruments. I was wondering if it's correct to say that someone's 'on vocals'? I mean, it's easy to imagine that someone's 'on guitar' but how does that work for vocals?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Usually in a list, you'll see it as this: Guitar - Richie Blackmore, Vocals - Candace Night, Willie Nelson, Johnny Cash.  "Candace Night on vocals" is how the band is usually introduced at a concert.

Comment: @KristinaLopez that's one hell of a lineup!

Comment: You betcha, @terdon! :-)

Comment: It's fascinating to see how the dictionaries at [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on) attempt valiantly to pin down all the senses of 'on'. Unless my eyes deceive me, only RHK Webster's lists this one: **on** (prep) 18. assigned to or working at: [ _Do you know who's on stewarding today?_ ] _Who's on the switchboard today?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search confirms that it's a commonly used phrase.  It's a bit idiomatic, but I would say it's well accepted and understood.

Comment: Thanks. I figured, however common use doesn't mean it's correct. Then again, I think in language a lot of wrongs _do_ make a right eventually, but I'm just trying not to make a fool of myself :) I'm going with it.